# I am trying to fetch image from a URL and make it as a thumbnail for my contacts in my application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I can fetch the image from a url and able to display the image in a `UIImageView` in my `DetailViewController`. I would like to display the same image from this URL as a thumbnail in my `tableviewcell`.

My viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.UrlField.text = contact.Imageurl
    let urlString = UrlField.text
    loadImageView(urlString)
 }

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let urlString = UrlField.text
    loadImageView(urlString)
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

In this function I try to fetch the image from the URL

```
func loadImageView(url : String){
    self.contact.Imageurl = url
    self.contact.data = nil
    let DatatoImage: (NSData?) -> Void = {
        if let d = $0  {
            let image = UIImage(data: d)
            self.imageView.image = image
        }else{
            self.imageView.image = nil
        }
    }
    if let d = contact.data {
        DatatoImage(d)
    } else {
        contact.loadImage(DatatoImage)
    }
}
```

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I managed to load an image that I have hardcoded in my folder and named it as "images1.jpeg"

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (named: "images1.jpeg", inBundle: nil, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

MainViewController

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, ContactDetailTableViewControllerDelegate {

var contacts: [ContactListEntry] = []
var currentContact: ContactListEntry!
var detailObject: ContactDetailTableViewController!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

@IBAction func addContact(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    currentContact = ContactListEntry(firstName: "", lastName: "", address: "", Imageurl: "")
    contacts.append(currentContact)        
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)

}

  /*  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if self.currentContact == nil || self.currentContact.isEmpty()
    {
        if count(contacts) > 0
        {
            contacts.removeLast()
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}*/

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

/*override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
// #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1
}*/

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
// #warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return contacts.count
}



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("contactcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(contact.firstName) \(contact.lastName)"
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (named: "images1.jpeg", inBundle: nil, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
    let url = NSURL(string: "<# place your URL here #>")



    return cell

}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return true
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        if (segue.identifier == "showDetail")
        {
            if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? ContactDetailTableViewController{


                let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
                currentContact = contacts[indexPath.row]
                dvc.contact = currentContact

            }}}

    if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? ContactDetailTableViewController
    {
        dvc.contact = currentContact
        dvc.delegate = self
    }
}



func masterViewController(dvc: ContactDetailTableViewController, didUpdate contact: Person)
{
    dvc.contact = currentContact
    dvc.delegate = self
    dvc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    navigationController?.popToViewController(self, animated: true)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    tableView.reloadData()

}




}
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: @Wraithseekerr I need to get the same image that I fetch from the url as a thumbnail in my contact image.

Comment: Try using AFNetworking or Alamofire. I used AFNetworking and there is a function in the library that allows you to download images from a URL and assign it to your imageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Create our configuration first In view did load */
let configuration =
NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0
configuration.URLCache=NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 4*1024*1024, diskCapacity: 20*1024*1024, diskPath: "CustomName"))
configuration.requestCachePolicy=NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;


/* Now create our session which will allow us to create the tasks */
var session: NSURLSession!
session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration,
  delegate: self,
  delegateQueue: nil)   



/* Now attempt to download the contents of the URL in tableView cellForRowAtIndexpath */
let url = NSURL(string: "<# place your URL here #>")

task=session.dataTaskWithRequest(url!, completionHandler: { (NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void in
   cell.imageView.image=UIImage(data: NSData))


})
task.start()
```

You can also set the cache,so that next tym when the request is fired then it is called from cache

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This should be in my cellForRowAtIndexpath?

Comment: yes,I have mentioned the comments.Intialise the session in viewdidload and then in  cellForRowAtIndexpath call the urlrequest

Comment: I am just pasting the URL in my URL textfield that is in my detailview controller. I want that url to be fetched.

Comment: so u can use the the same code wherever u want with url and cell.imageView variable as changed

Comment: Thanks, So I do want to initialise my "session" somewhere and where shud I do it??

Comment: appdelegate will good place to init the sessionand cache.I have the answer for cache init also

Comment: I have not done anything in my appdelegate till now any of my works. Can you please guide me through this.??

Comment: its fine .U can paste in ur ViewController also

Comment: I have pasted my MainViewController aka MasterTableViewController.
Thanks :-)

Comment: Also if you dont want to go with these complexities then use AFNEtworking and u just have to call         [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_profilepic.png"]];.Search for AFNetworking download and add the files in to ur project.Then u dont have to worry about these complexities

Comment: I dont want to put the image in my project, rather I want it from that URL only. So how should I edit my Master to get the image from that URL?

Comment: yes the above code is getting the image from url.Please look the code carefully.That is the placeholder image .If image not downloaded

Comment: I added the AFNetworking to my project. But the code that you suggested shows error.

Comment: you have to include these headers  import AFNetworking.h
    import UIImageView+AFNetworking.h.Re-written in Swift

Comment: Why does an error occur at ":" just after the setImageWithURL?
I have got errors near all these ":"'s in the code..!!!

Comment: i have given in Obj-C try to find in swift.In Afnetworking github you will find the example how to use libraries